# Evaluating function of two variables inside NMinimize with respect to second argument

Tags: mathematical-optimization, evaluation, hold

Consider three functions:

```
f[t_, 1] := {Cos[t], 1, 0}
f[t_, 2] := {Sin[2 t], 1, 0}
f[t_, 3] := {Cos[t - 2], 1, 0}
```

For each $k=1,2,3$, let $g(\cdot,k)$ be the derivative of $f(\cdot,k)$ with respect to $t$:

```
g[t_, k_] := D[f[t, k], t]
```

For each value of $t$, I would like to compute the minimum distance between the point  $g(t,k)$ and the graph of $f(\cdot, k+1)$. To this end, I tried the following code:

```
x[t_, k_] := NMinimize[EuclideanDistance[g[t, k], f[x, k + 1]], x]
```

As one can check, calling e.g. `x[1,1]` gives errors.

I think I understand what the problem is, but I am not able to find a solution. On one hand, the code is faulty because calling `x[1,1]` results in Mathematica triying to compute `D[f[1, k], 1]`. On the other hand, evaluating `EuclideanDistance` without numerical values for $k$ does not make any sense either. What I need, instead, is to evaluate the expression inside `EuclideanDistance` only with respect to $k$, then to take the derivative with respect to $t$, and finally to evaluate with respect to $t$.

Does anybody know what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Does `g[t2_, k_] := D[f[t, k], t] /. t -> t2` for your definition of `g` do what you want?

Comment: Yes, it does! Thanks for the help. However, I remain a little confused because still `Plot[g[t, 1], {t, 0, 1}]` gives errors, whereas `Plot[Evaluate[g[t, 1]], {t, 0, 1}]` works fine. So I am wondering whether I really understand your solution.

Comment: The issue with that command is that `Plot` sets `t` to a numeric value before evaluating `g`. To prevent such issues, you can either replace `t` inside `g` with some variable that you will never assign a value to (e.g. ``Formal`t`` or `\[FormalT]`), or you can wrap the body of `g` in `Block` (i.e. `g[t2_, k_] := Block[{t},D[f[t,k],t]/.t->t2]`)